# How to delete cassandra row with bad primary key, since Cassandra C# Driver Complains Timestamp type column out of range

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

I have a piece of C# code like this,

```
RowSet rows = cassandraSession.Execute("select * from mytable");
foreach( var row in rows)
{
    DateTimeOffset dt = (DateTimeOffset)row["last_modified"];
    // Construct the primary key and delete an row ....
}
```

when I insert data into mytable, I put DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks as the value of column "last_modified" [timestamp]. However, when the code above runs, it always throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException in the row["last_modified"].

Unfortunately, last_modified is part of the primary key and I cannot query it out and delete now.

Any thoughts and solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra `timestamp` is represented in the C# driver as `DateTimeOffset` (not the long value of the ticks).

To get the columns that are retrieved as part of the `RowSet`, you can use the `Columns` property.

```
RowSet rs = cassandraSession.Execute("select * from mytable");
//Print all the column names
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", "), rs.Columns.Select(c => c.Name));
foreach (var row in rs)
{
    //Use the typed GetValue<T>() method
    DateTimeOffset dt = row.GetValue<DateTimeOffset>("last_modified");
}
```

Comment: Hi Jorgebg, the problem is not solved by refactoring the code. the line row.GetValue will still throw, and I cannot construct my primary key for deletion.

Comment: Check the columns returned, is `last_modified` column included?